# Area Stacked linewidth

Tags: highcharts

I am having trouble eliminating the line width between series on a stacked area chart. I have set the linewidth to zero however there are artifacts of it there. I could set the linewidth to 1 and set the color to the graph but lines can not be set to gradients which will be my final presentation.

```
plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 0,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: '#666666'
            },
            fillColor: "#000000",
        }
    }
```

Please see the example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xs8fL79L/1/)

Comment: Without having a solution, I'd say this is in fact the complete opposite. It isn't the line showing, it's the chart background. Set `chart.backgroundColor` to black, and it's gone. Now how you would "bloat" the area to prevent a gap between the different areas I do not know.

Comment: great observation, it would be interesting to bloat the area 1px but i have no idea how.

Comment: Adding an offset to nudge each series up or down by i + (i +1) would work as well, I am not sure how apply such control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by shapes rendering in SVG.

Simple CSS to change that:

```
svg {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xs8fL79L/3/